# How would you edit a photo to get a darkened face (See examples)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How would you edit an photo to get a darkened face?
It's hard to explain, but how would you get this edit in photoshop?
[Photo 1](http://instagram.com/p/oFVZ-ayW4L/)
[Photo 2](http://instagram.com/p/oQIIf-SW1Z/)

Well here's the image i'm editing:

[image]

Comment: Just select the area within the hood, then proceed to use the darken brush. :)

Comment: Easy, just creat a new layer and use the brush to paint the face in either or a very dark grey/purple so it doesn't look too dark and out of place. also make sure the brush has a hardness at about 60%

Comment: Cheers. So simple...haha @SaturnsEye

Comment: No worries pal :)

Comment: It might be helpful to review [the types of questions](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which should and should not be asked. Specifically what to [avoid asking](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). **Simple "how to" question" are customarily not desirable.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Grab a Brush
- Hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> down and sample the color just inside the edge of the hood.
- Paint over the face (on the same layer or a new layer, doesn't matter.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although using a lasso (magnetic one would be better) is good, the best way I'd see is to use the Quick-Mask, and paint over the face, then make the selection and adjust levels to your satisfaction.